# Is JSONP a must for your API?

Tags: wcf, json, api, jsonp

I have a WCF API which supports SOAP/JSON/XML but we don't provide JSONP.
This means if someone wants to consume our API using JSON they must create a server side proxy to get around the cross browser limitation.

I kind of like this since it discourages users from putting api keys and secrets in client side code.  While most methods accept and access token, we have auth methods which require the consumer to send key and secret to get this access token. If we expose JSONP some consumers may make this request client side and I'm not thrilled with that.

So... if you have an API that supports JSON, is it essential to support JSONP.
Is it terrible to require consumers to create a server side proxy?

JSONP is not hard to implement but for reason stated above I'm hesitant.
Kinda just looking for thoughts/advice.
Thanks

Comment: That entirely depends on what kind of consumers you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This makes sense!  
We have partners that use all different languages to interface with our system. PHP, .NET, and Front End developers that like JavaScript. Our partners make all sorts of apps with our data thy get from the API. So I want to make the API as easy to consumer as possible for a lot of different consumers which is why I want to expose the JSONP -  but not sure if I have a valid security concern against doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make special auth keys that only work with JSONP, then return Javascript that checks `location` and makes sure that the auth key was used by a valid site.

However, that won't stop a malicious server from sending a JSONP request and parsing out the JSON.

You need to figure out what your partners want and what attackers might to do make the trade-off between usability and security.

Comment: can we chat about this sometime? I've got a fresh JSON api and I'm trying to get expert opinions on security measures. I'd love to crack your brain for a half hour or so if you wouldn't mind a chat?